# Hotkey wont work if its modifier is also being used as part of the trigger

Tags: windows, autohotkey

This issue seems to only occur in this one program.

I have the hotkey `Shift`+`a` set in this programs hotkey editor dialog, I want to trigger it in AHK using `Rshift` and `w`;

```
RShift & w::
SendInput, +{a}
Return
```

For the life of me, it will not work. I press `Rshift` and `w` and nothing happens at all.  Triggering the hotkey manually by pressing `shift` and `a` works just fine.
The strange thing is the following works:

```
LCtrl & w::
SendInput, +{a}
Return
```

So does this:

```
w::
SendInput, +{a}
Return
```

I also tried to send Rshift back up before triggering the hotkey, no luck:

```
RShift & w::
SendInput, {RShift up}
SendInput, +{a}
Return
```

Is there a rule that says you cant use the same modifier as the target hotkey in the trigger that I missed?
please dont suggest that I use other modifier keys, `shift` +`[key]` is all that I have left.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use a [custom hotkey combination](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) when a [modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) exists (unless you have a good reason to):

> For standard modifier keys, normal hotkeys typically work as well or better than "custom" combinations. For example, `<+s::` is recommended over `LShift & s::`.

And secondly you shouldn't escape keys in a `Send`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)</sup> command that don't need escaping:

> Enclosing a plain ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) in braces forces it to be sent as the corresponding virtual keycode, even if the character does not exist on the current keyboard layout. In other words, `Send a` produces the letter "a" while `Send {a}` may or may not produce "a", depending on the keyboard layout. For details, see the remarks below.

---

And then about the problem itself:
I of course can't know if this will work, but I'd simply try the following:

```
>+w::a
```

This would work because because the remapping syntax [actually uses](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#actually) the blind sendmode.
Alternatively, you could, of course, just manually use the [blind sendmode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind):

```
>+w::SendInput, {Blind}a
```

Comment: Oh man the second suggestion worked, thansk so much. I will read further into the links you shared! thanks!